# Precise Membership Test in Python

Tags: python

The `in` operator tests for equivalence using comparison, but Python's comparison isn't precise in the sense that True == 1 and 0 == False, yielding -

```
>>> True in [ 1 ]
True
>>> False in [ 0 ]
True
>>> 1 in [ True ]
True
>>> 0 in [ False ]
True
```

whereas I need a precise comparison (similar to === in other languages) that would yield False in all of the above examples. I could of course iterate over the list:

```
res = False
for member in mylist:
    if subject == member and type( subject ) == type( member ):
        res = True
        break
```

This is obviously much less efficient then using the builtin `in` operator, even if I pack it as a list comprehension. Is there some native alternative to `in` such as a list method or some way to tweak `in`'s behavior to get the required result?

The `in` operator is used in my case for testing the uniqueness of all list members, so a native uniqueness test would do as well.

Important note: The list may contain mutable values, so using `set` isn't an option.

Python version is 3.4, would be great for the solution to work on 2.7 too.

**EDIT TO ALL THOSE WHO SUGGEST USING `IS`:**

1. I look for a non-iterating, native alternative to `a in b`.
2. The `is` operator is not relevant for this case. For example, in the following situation `in` works just fine but `is` won't:

   ```
   >>> [1,2] in [[1,2]]
   True
   ```

Please, do read the question before answering it...

Comment: You're looking for the `is` operator: `if any(x is True for x in l): ...`

Comment: @Blender in the question I said that I'm looking for a native solution, I know how to iterate over the list as you can see from the question... besides, `is` won't work for other types such as list, dict, classes, etc., the comparison I need is as per the question, similar to other languages' ===

Comment: How would `===` work in the case of an object where `YourClass.__eq__` always returns `True`?

Comment: @Blender, just as `in` works. The only situation I found so far where `in` breaks is when you want 1 and True, 0 and False, to be non-equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `in` operator is precise and the behavior you're complaining of is perfectly expected, since `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Below is the excerpt of the official [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) describing the *boolean* type:

> Booleans
>
> These represent the truth values False and True. The two objects representing   the values False and True are the only Boolean objects. The Boolean type is a   subtype of plain integers, and Boolean values behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all contexts, the exception being that when converted to a string, the strings "False" or "True" are returned, respectively.

You can also have a look at [PEP 285](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/).

Comment: Thanks, that explains the behavior. BTW, I'm not complaining, I just needed to implement some code that tests for uniqueness of json array members; in a json `[1,true]` all members would be unique, and `1 in [2,true]` should return `false`, hence mandating "my" `in` function, which ended up less efficient than it would e.g. in javascript as Python lacks a native === operator...

Comment: Sorry, avnr, I should have used "experiencing" instead of "complaining of". However, depending on the kind of data present in your list, you could try to replace `item in iterable` with `str(item) in map(str, iterable)`.

Answer (score 3):

`in` doesn't test for equivalence at all. It checks if an item is in a container. Example:

```
>>> 5 in [1,2,3,4,5]
True
>>> 6 in [1,2,3,4,5]
False
>>> True in {True, False}
True
>>> "k" in ("b","c")
True
```

What you are looking for is `is`.

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> True is 1
False
>>> False == 0
True
>>> False is 0
False
```

**EDIT**

After reading your edit, I don't think there is something built in in python libraries that suits your needs. What you want is basically to differentiate between `int` and `bool (True, False).` But python itself treats `True` and `False` as integers. This is because `bool` is a subclass of `int`. Which is why `True == 1` and  `False==0` evaluates to true. You can even do:

```
>>> isinstance ( True, int)
True
```

I cannot think of anything better than your own solution, However, if your list is certain to contain any item not more than once you can use `list.index()`

```
try:
    index_val = mylist.index(subject)
except ValueError:
    index_val = None

if (index_val!=None):
    return type(subject) == type(member)
```

Since index is built-in, it might be a little faster, though rather inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `is` operator:

```
if any(x is True for x in l):
    ...
```

`is`, however, isn't exactly `===` from other languages. `is` checks identity, not just equality without type coercion. Since CPython uses string and integer interning, two objects that are equal may not be the same object:

```
In [19]: a = '12'

In [20]: b = '123'

In [21]: a += '3'

In [22]: a is b
Out[22]: False

In [23]: a == b
Out[23]: True

In [27]: 100001 is 100000 + 1
Out[27]: False

In [28]: 100001 == 100000 + 1
Out[28]: True
```

In Python 3, `None`, `True`, and `False` are essentially singletons, so using `is` for discerning `True` from `1` will work perfectly fine. In Python 2, however, this is possible:

```
In [29]: True = 1

In [31]: True is 1
Out[31]: True
```

Equality can be overridden `__eq__` method, so you can define an object that is equal to any other object:

```
In [1]: %paste
    class Test(object):
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return True

## -- End pasted text --

In [2]: x = Test()

In [3]: x == None
Out[3]: True

In [4]: x == True
Out[4]: True

In [5]: x == False
Out[5]: True
```

In this case, how would `===` work? There is no general solution, so Python has no built-in method of lists that does what you want.

Comment: subject == member and type( subject ) == type( member )